# Using binding to Linear Layout and Setting an Image but ontop of the pervious View (Image)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm having an issue with this for two days now... I have a binding and an image to pop when clicking a button.
I want that every time the button is pressed another image will pop either next to the pervious one, or, if there's no space in the linear layout, that it will pop ontop of the previous one.
The idea is to get a card from a card deck and put it ot the hand of the player.

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityPlayTableBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        var image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.fight_deck)
        var i: Int = 1
        val deck = Deck()
        var deckListOfCards: MutableList<Card> = deck.shuffledDeckOfCard()
        val deck_clickable_top = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.deck_button)
        val imageView = ImageView(this)
        val Width = convertDpToPixel(135f, this)
        val Height = convertDpToPixel(190f, this)
        imageView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Width.toInt(), Height.toInt())
        var imgResId: Int = 0
        deck_clickable_top.setOnClickListener {
            if (deckListOfCards.size != 0) {
                imgResId = deckListOfCards.get(0).getCardFace()
                i += 1
                deck.removeCardFromDeck(deckListOfCards.get(0))
            }
            if (deckListOfCards.size == 0) {
                deck_clickable_top.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                deck_clickable_top.layoutParams.height = 0
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(imgResId)
        }
        binding.bottomLinearLayout.addView(imageView)
    }
```

I can't figure out how to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, LinearLayout doesn't seem like a good choice for this, but you can try something along these lines:

```
// step 1 - this is the linear layout you'll use as the container
val containerBinding = CustomLinearLayoutContainerBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

// step 2 - on some click event you can create a new binding, this should contain you image
val componentBinding = CustomComponentLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
     // set the image drawable here, text, any other data in here
}

// step 3 - the root layout of that binding is the linear layout
containerBinding.root.addView(componentBinding.root)

// the following 2 methods of LinearLayout can be very handy
removeAllViews() // to remove all previously added children
invalidate() // to re-render the linear layout
```

But please note that everything you want to do with those views after you added them will need manual changes and again, this doesn't feel like you should go for it. However, I found this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stackview-in-android/#:%7E:text=StackView%20is%20a%20widget%20that,behind%20comes%20to%20the%20front.), check out this implementation, feels like this suits your requirements better.

Comment: Hi Marton, thanks for the input. Do you think it might be better to use JetPack instead of manually work with views?

Comment: What do you mean? Jetpack or not, you'll have to work with views. My advice is go with a solution that has an adapter class, so you'll just pass the data objects you want to render and the adapter will render it for you - it's much better that way.